# R split one column into multiple

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
Car MPG
Volvo 10
Tesla 12
Ford 8
Volvo 12
Tesla 11
Ford 7
```

Multiple occurences of `Car` here are replicates and I want them in separate columns so that my final dataframe looks like:

```
Car    MPG1   MPG2
Volvo    10     12
Tesla    12     11
Ford      8      7
```

I am new to R and I think there might be some inbuilt function for this but I don't know where to search for in the documentation

Comment: Do all of the values in the first column have the same number of entries? Is the pattern clearly repeating?

Comment: Using the answer from the duplicate: `library(dplyr); library(tidyr); dd %>% mutate(id=row_number(), .by=Car) %>% pivot_wider(names_from=id, values_from=MPG, names_glue="{.value}{id}")`